# Why does apply F to a fixed point show that its a fixed point?

Tags: continuity, computer-science, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I was learning fixed points in the context of programming languages and [the text wants](http://fsl.cs.illinois.edu/images/c/ca/CS522-Fall-2018-basic-semantics.pdf) on page 89 wants to show that $fix(\mathcal F)$ is a fix point by applying $\mathcal F$ to the fix point itself. Why is that?

Right now we define the fix point as the least upper bound (LUB) of a the chain $ \bot \leq \mathcal F( \bot) \leq \mathcal F^2( \bot) \leq ...$ bottomed complete partial order (BCPO). How does apply the (continuous) function to the fix point show its a LUB of the chain in question?

I would have thought the fixed point was obvious a fixed point **by definition** but it seems we actually have to manipulate it to show this...

---

Note that in wikipedia and other sources fixed points are defined as points that continuous application of a rule leads to the same element. I assume that should be a consequence of the LUB definition we gave above but thats NOT how we show fixed points YET.

---

---

I understand the steps of the proof just not the rationale of the first step, why are we applying $\mathcal F$?

[image]

Comment: $fix(\mathcal F)$ is defined as a LUB of a chain of expressions. This certainly doesn't say that $fix(\mathcal F)$ is a fixed point by definition. Instead, for $z$ to be a fixed point of $\mathcal F$, $z$ should satisfy $\mathcal F(z)=z$. This is exactly what the proof shows for $z=fix(\mathcal F)$.

Comment: I don't get it, they never say that the definition of a fixed point is $\mathcal F(z) = z$. I thought just merely the definition of LUB would induce that property instead of just invoking it randomly.

Comment: The notes you linked to appear to be an excerpt from a book. Note that Chapter 2 starts at section 2.6. Presumably, in the original book the definition of fixed point is given in one of the five sections preceding section 2.6. That said, the [definition of fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) is relatively consistent across mathematics.

Comment: @DerekElkins so it cannot be derived from the property I quoted? I know what it usually is, but Im trying to make sure Im not making assumptions